# Is there an Italian equivalent for something that is figuratively addictive?

Tags: word-choice

Upon searching for a figurative sense for *addictive* in Italian, I have not found an entry that is sufficient for describing the sense of being drawn to something so much that you want to do it often.

For example:

> Social media is so addictive; I could stay on Facebook for days.

[Wordreference.com](http://www.wordreference.com/enit/addictive) fails to find a sufficient term for this:

> *addictive* adj *figurative* (activity: habit-forming)    ***traduzione non disponibile***
>
> *A lot of people find yoga addictive after a month or so.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best translation derives from *[assuefare](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/tag/assuefazione/)*. Which means exactly what you want to say

> describing the sense of being drawn to something so much that you want to do it often.

Translation of your examples using *assuefare*

> I social media sono molto **assuefacenti**; posso stare su Facebook per giorni.

and

> Molte persone trovano lo yoga **assuefacente** dopo un mese

and to confirm it, I found right now a reference to a dictionary Italian to English: [assuefacente](http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano-Inglese/A/assuefacente.php).

Answer (score 3):

The literal meaning can be given in Italian as *che dà assuefazione* (or the uncommon, and already recorded, *assuefacente*), but in the figurative uses one would rather use *avvincente* (having a not-too-distant literal meaning: “something that binds”), *appassionante* and the like.

Answer (score 3):

I think the above *"avvincente"* doesn't convey the exact meaning of "addicting" at all. In fact, "avvincente" means something that is exciting, absorbing or really interesting: "una storia avvincente".

*"Assuefacente"* sounds too complicated a word (even for Italian standards) for every-day speech.

I have two different translations for "addicting":

- "Social media is so addictive; I could stay on Facebook for days" = *"I social network **sono una droga**; potrei stare su Facebook per giorni"*. This is a very informal expression, that you can use with friends or family. It perfectly reflects the English meaning of "something addictive like a drug."
- "A lot of people find yoga addictive after a month or so" = "In molte persone lo yoga **crea dipendenza** dopo un mese circa". This expression can be used in a formal context, but won't sound unnatural even if you use it with friends: it will just show that you have proper knowledge of the language!

  "Crea" is the verb "creare": io creo, tu crei, egli crea, noi creiamo, voi create, essi creano.

As for the expression *"I'm addicted to...."*:

-"I'm addicted to you" = "Mi crei dipendenza" / "Sei la mia droga" (Watch out: don't say "Sono dipendente da te"/"dipendo da te" has a slightly different meaning: it means "I depend on you").

-"I'm addicted to yoga" can be translated with "Lo yoga è la mia droga", "Sono drogato di yoga" (both informal), "Non posso fare a meno dello yoga", "non posso vivere senza lo yoga".

Comment: “*È una droga*” and “*crea dipendenza*” are certainly good translations for the uses of “addictive” (or “addicting”) closer to the literal meaning. When suggesting “*avvincente*” and the like, I had more in mind the very frequent use of “addictive”, say, in the blurb of a game, an app, a recreative activity. In Italian you wouldn't try to sell a game saying that it *crea dipendenza*, while in English all games are addictive (just like all action novels are compelling, love stories are heartbreaking and so on).